# Static files are not found/served to a SPA when files are outside the wwwroot

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-areas

I created a asp.net core 1.0 website project with multiple areas.

In the application area`s HomeController I have this action:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    string content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("./Areas/Application/App/Index.html");
    return base.Content(content, new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
}
```

When the html file is returned many 404 errors from not found javascript library files occur in my browser.

The index.html with all its .js files is a SPA inside a asp.net core website area.

This SPA is built + deployed to the websiteproject/areas/application/App folder.

When I build + deploy the SPA **to the wwwroot** folder then all the static files **are found**.

I guess this means the static file path is always relative to wwwroot to make the SPA work.

**Question 1**: Is there any way to configure the wwwroot folder as wwwroot/app path with the WebHostBuilder class via:

```
 .UseWebRoot("./wwwroot/app")
```

**just** and **explicitly** for the **application area**?

That means the wwwroot for the website should continue to work?

The best thing I would achieve is a wwwroot folder with 2 subfolders:

- website
- app

and I would like to configure 2 wwwroot`s path website and app for default 'area' and the explicit application area.

**Question 2:** How can I do that?

**UPDATE 1**

According to Pawel comment I changed:

```
   app.UseStaticFiles();
```

**to**:

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Areas","Application", "App")),
    RequestPath = new PathString("/Application")
});
```

But still I get the same 404 errors for the .js file as if they would not be available in the wwwroot directory ???

**404**
  In the developer console tools requested by the single page app:

```
http://localhost:52159/vendor/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js (404)
```

**200**
  Entered manually in the browser url bar:

```
http://localhost:52159/Application/vendor/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js
```

Does that mean the static file serving in asp.net core works, but there is something else which works not somehow? I guess I should not change something in the SPA that would be stupid...

I added a screenshot of my file structure that you guys better understand my problem or maybe find my user error...:

[image]

Comment: Have you read this: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/static-files.html?

Comment: Pawel I updated my question with a comment to you!

Comment: Ok I found the problem. Its my my angular 2 app and the index.html. During build time the path vendor/angular2.js is correct to debug the app. But when I start the asp.net website the path to vendor need Application/vendor everywhere due to the static file path change in the Startup.cs. And even when I changed all path in the index.html it does down to each component.ts file that it cant be found. Seems I must create a new system.js module loader question about prepending 'Application' when its modules are loading before each component etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I found a solution where  have to apply the changes.

**system.config.ts**

```
System.config({
  map: {
    '@angular': 'Application/vendor/@angular',
    'rxjs': 'Application/vendor/rxjs',
    'main': 'Application/main.js',
    'app': 'Application/app',
  },
  packages: cliSystemConfigPackages
});
```

That way all angular 2/rxjs files are served from the directory path:

"Area/Application/App" when the url "/Application" is entered.

Also I had to prepend 'Application' to the main and the root barrel 'app'.

**index.html**

```
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>

    {{#each scripts.polyfills}}
    <script src="Application/{{.}}"></script>
    {{/each}}
    <script>
      System.import('Application/system-config.js').then(function () {
        System.import('Application/main.js');
      }).catch(console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

These are the changes in the index.html file.

Now my Asp.net core Area 'Application' has its own "wwwroot" separated from the wwwroot of the public website.